# C# Directory-Searchpattern Subdirectorie(s)

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory

How can I search a Path like that in C#:

"C:\MyApp\*\log"

I want to get all Directories that matches that search pattern.

Example result:
C:\MyApp\20171009\log
C:\MyApp\20171008\log
C:\MyApp\20171007\log

In Powershell it works with get-item

Comment: You'd have to implement such an algorithm yourself

Comment: You could try to run the PowerShell command using `RunspaceInvoke`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this iterator-based file functions:

```
var path = @"C:\temp";
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

For more informations show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just get the directories with Name Log which match the pattern C:\MyApp*\log, following code should help:

```
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Temp\","log", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Notice that search pattern is the name of directory and not any file name or file extension

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753047/multiple-wildcard-directory-file-search-for-arbitrary-directory-structure-in-c-s) for my Problem.

I modified it for Directory-Use.

```
public static List<string> GetAllMatchingPaths(string pattern)
        {
            char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            string[] parts = pattern.Split(separator);

            if (parts[0].Contains('*') || parts[0].Contains('?'))
                throw new ArgumentException("path root must not have a wildcard", nameof(parts));

            return GetAllMatchingPathsInternal(String.Join(separator.ToString(), parts.Skip(1)), parts[0]);
        }

        private static List<string> GetAllMatchingPathsInternal(string pattern, string root)
        {
            char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            string[] parts = pattern.Split(separator);

            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                // if this part of the path is a wildcard that needs expanding
                if (parts[i].Contains('*') || parts[i].Contains('?'))
                {
                    // create an absolute path up to the current wildcard and check if it exists
                    var combined = root + separator + String.Join(separator.ToString(), parts.Take(i));
                    if (!Directory.Exists(combined))
                        return new List<string>();

                    if (i == parts.Length - 1) // if this is the end of the path (a file name)
                    {
                        return ( List<string> ) Directory.EnumerateFiles(combined, parts[i], SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                    }
                    else // if this is in the middle of the path (a directory name)
                    {
                        var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(combined, parts[i], SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

                        List<string> pts = new List<string>();
                        foreach ( string directory in directories )
                        {
                            foreach ( string item in GetAllMatchingPathsInternal(String.Join(separator.ToString(), parts.Skip(i + 1)), directory))
                            {

                                pts.Add(item);
                            }

                        }

                        return pts;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: were you not able to get the list of dir with the answer I provided?