# Searching for directories with wildcard mid in path

Tags: c#, path, wildcard, getdirectories

I want to get all directories that match a search-pattern with a wildcard mid in the path, e.g.

```
C:\\folder1\\folder2\\*\\nextFolder\\lastFolder
```

Is there any chance to get them with a function-call?

I've tried to use `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()`,
but it seems, that for this function a wildcard is only allowed inside the last part of the path, as in:

```
C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\nextFolder\\last*
```

or

```
C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\nextFolder\\*
```

Here some additional information and the sourcecode I used with the given feedback:
Environment: Windows, Visual Studio 2022, .NET Framework 4.6.2
Existing directories:
C:\MESDataTransfer\Csv_Cnc_to_Mes_Prod\job\ABD\MultiParts01
C:\MESDataTransfer\Csv_Cnc_to_Mes_Prod\job\BHX500\MultiParts01
As result I get directoryPaths.Message = "Die Anfrage ist ungültig" and directoryPaths.ErrorCode = InvalidQuery.
Same error, if I replace "%" with a existing foldername "ABD".
Is the syntax of @"\.\ROOT\cimv2"  for ManagementScope correct? Seems to be the value for UTF16. Is this always correct?

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\ROOT\cimv2");
string[] selectProps = { "Path" };
var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Directory",
    @"Drive = 'C:' and Path Like 'MESDataTransfer\Csv_Cnc_to_Mes_Prod\job\%\MultiParts01'",
    selectProps);

using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    using (var instances = searcher.Get())
    {
        var directoryPaths = instances.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(mo => mo["Path"]);

        // enumerate the collection.
        int nCount = 0;
        foreach (string directoryPath in directoryPaths)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(directoryPath);
            string asString = directoryPath.ToString();
            ++nCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to search all sub folder for "C:\folder1\folder2\" and for each check if they end with "\nextFolder\lastFolder" but that can be a long task for exemple if you need to get each folder from "C:\"

Comment: of course, that's a possible solution, but I hope to find a simplier way

Comment: Have you see this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753047/multiple-wildcard-directory-file-search-for-arbitrary-directory-structure-in-c-s

Comment: @SioGabx : Thx, no, I haven't seen it.  I tried it and it works fine!  But I have to check whether I can use PowerShell-commands in my context.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a WMI directory query.
It accepts wildcards for any part of the path, not just for the token at the end, aka the name.
 The pendant for the Win32 '*' wildcard is a '%'.

```
    // needs a reference to System.Management (nuget or assembly)
    
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\ROOT\cimv2");

    string[] selectProps = { "Path" };
    var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Directory",
          @"Drive = 'C:' and Path Like 'folder1\folder2\%\nextFolder\lastFolder'", 
          selectProps);

    using var searcher  = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    using var instances = searcher.Get();
    var directoryPaths  = instances.Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(mo => mo["Path"]);

    // enumerate the collection.
    foreach (string directoryPath in directoryPaths)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(directoryPath);
    }
```

If you need more details of the directories returned, than just the "Path" itself, you can add the properties wanted to the 'selectProps' array. Win32_Directory has about the same set of properties, if not more, as System.IO.DirectoryInfo has: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response, but it doesn't work in my enwironment. I get the result that the selection is invalid (in German: "Die Anfrage ist ungültig").  Maybe because I have to use .NET Framework 4.6.2 .   And because I don't know anything of "System.Management"  I will realise it in an other not so comfortable way. :-)

Comment: Hi it's up to you how to solve it. 'Die Anfrage ist ungültig" just means that there is a syntax error in the "WQL" statement; WQL = WMI SQL (Bin auch Deutscher ;) ). Most often there is just a apostrophe missing or a backslash too little or too much in the query text. The example I have posted for example uses a verbatim string (starting with @) in order to just have to use one backsalsh as folder-separator. If you use a normal string you need to double the backslashes. Also, the Path and the Drive argument need to be surrounded by single quotes.