# GetFileSystemInfos() for an arbitrary path (with wildcards) rather than for a certain DirectoryInfo

Tags: .net, path

I need to get a list of files *and* directories corresponding to a given arbitrary path, e.g. `\foo\bar\*.txt`. Essentially, the same result as would `dir` with this path produce.

Ideally, it should be an array of `FileSystemInfo` rather than of expanded file names/path strings.

When starting from a certain root directory, the solution is simply

```
a = new DirectoryInfo(root_path);
return a.GetFileSystemInfos(my_pattern);
```

But this time I don't have a defined `root_path`; `my_pattern` is arbitrary and can be relative, absolute or UNC path.

For simplicity, let's assume I don't need to [parse wildcards recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13478121/3513925), i.e. `paths\*\like*\this?.txt`. Wildcards can only appear in the last part (but the pattern can still match a file or a directory).

I could split `my_pattern` into 'directory' and 'file' parts (using `IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` etc., and then treat them like above. But this feels overcomplicated for the task, given that I have to deal separately with cases when one of such parts is empty.

If I could get `DirectoryInfo` for the 'computer root', from which even absolute paths would be valid, it would be easy, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

It *feels* like this should be a one-liner, but I can't find it in .NET...

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly that's basically all you have in in the .NET Framework. 
You can do as you suggest e.g.

```
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
var file = Path.GetFileName(path);

// Determine if the path is a file path with wildcards
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory) 
    &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) 
    && (file.Contains("*") || file.Contains("?")))
{
    foreach (var match in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, file))
    {
        DeleteFile(match);
    }
}
else
{
    // TODO handling of path without wildcards
}
```

The alternative is to use the non-portable Windows API FindFirstFileEx (etc.) functions.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange MS didn't think of making, say, a static method like `Directory.GetFileSystemInfos()` for this common purpose; but this is not the first time I run into inexplicable limitations in .NET... Re your example, I don't thing it's necessary to treat wildcard-conraining paths separately: a literal exact path is still a match on itself. But empty `directory` still needs protection.